# How to add links to images on a Project Page in Squarespace using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, squarespace

I'm working on a website using Squarespace. Squarespace's project pages allow you to add images with a title and description, but you don't have any direct access to edit the page. They currently don't offer the ability to make the images clickthroughs, so I'm trying to use JQuery to add that to the images myself.

Here is the website page I'm working on: [Prestigious Affairs](http://prestigiousaffairs.biz)

Since the div ids change on every load, I'm trying to use the class of the images used for the project page (project-slide-image) to target them, then using .wrap() to add the href. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong, because it sort of works, but the whole section pulses and it messes up the title and description on all of the left offset imgaes.

```
$(function(){
    $("img.project-slide-image:eq(0)").wrap('<a href="/about-us/"></a>');
    $("img.project-slide-image:eq(1)").wrap('<a href="/events/"></a>');
    $("img.project-slide-image:eq(2)").wrap('<a href="/prom/"></a>');
    $("img.project-slide-image:eq(3)").wrap('<a href="/weddings/"></a>');
    $("img.project-slide-image:eq(4)").wrap('<a href="/floral/"></a>');
    $("img.project-slide-image:eq(5)").wrap('<a href="/contact-us/"></a>');
});
```

It seems to be working, albeit slightly different, here: [Code Snippet](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDVZOWD66K3P)

Comment: Okay, I figured out that the reason it's breaking it is because they've put the images inside of <figure></figure> tags. So, if I wrap the href around the whole <figure> tag, it works. But now I'm stuck with a link that extends beyond the actual image. Can anyone suggest a way to make only the image clickable?

Answer (score 0):

So, after quite a bit of messing around, I managed to figure out a solution. I realize this is probably only relevant to Squarespace, but maybe the code would come in handy in some other situation for someone, so I'll go ahead an post it. I ended up using .insertBefore instead of .wrap since that was causing problems.

This is the JQuery I ended up using:

```
$(function(){
  $('<div class="mainLinksOuter"><a href="/about-us/"><div class="mainLinksRight"></div></a></div>').insertBefore($("figure:eq(0)"));  
  $('<div class="mainLinksOuter"><a href="/events/"><div class="mainLinksLeft"></div></a></div>').insertBefore($("figure:eq(1)"));
  $('<div class="mainLinksOuter"><a href="/prom/"><div class="mainLinksRight"></div></a></div>').insertBefore($("figure:eq(2)"));
  $('<div class="mainLinksOuter"><a href="/weddings/"><div class="mainLinksLeft"></div></a></div>').insertBefore($("figure:eq(3)"));
  $('<div class="mainLinksOuter"><a href="/floral/"><div class="mainLinksRight"></div></a></div>').insertBefore($("figure:eq(4)"));
  $('<div class="mainLinksOuter"><a href="/contact-us/"><div class="mainLinksLeft"></div></a></div>').insertBefore($("figure:eq(5)"));
});
```

So, I ended up inserting the href surrounding a DIV so I could control the size to make sure it would match the image size. I had to do a class for CSS formatting the links that are on the right side of the page and a separate one for the links on the left side in order to keep the inner DIV on top of the images, because of how the Squarespace template works. And then a class for the Outer DIV to add CSS formatting to it.

I then put that inside another DIV to be able to position it where I wanted on the page. Without doing that, I wasn't able to control where the DIV surround by the href ended up, and the site formatting changed for mobile at 768px wide and at 640px wide, so I had to adjust the CSS for those instances.

So, basically, what I end up with is an empty DIV with an href surround it on top of each image, remaining over top of them and adjusting size with the responsive design.